# Sharing image using intent with Glide library- Image is null always

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-glide

I have a custom listview which is working good, now i want to share the image and text from the list. I have found a step how to do it from SO but image is always null when i click on Share button.

The imageview loading images using Glide.

```
if (!Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(Limage).matches()) {
viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage).centerCrop()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                           @Override
                           public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                               return false;
                           }

                           @Override
                           public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                             //  viewholder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               return false;
                           }
                       }).into(viewholder.iview);
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

I have created a Share button and inside onclick i am passing the below code.

```
viewholder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(viewholder.iview);
                if (bmpUri != null) {
                    // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                    // Launch sharing dialog for image
                    listdisplay.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));

                } else {
                    // ...sharing failed, handle error
                }

            }
        });
```

To get image from Imageview i am using the below code.

```
   private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView iview) {
        Drawable drawable = iview.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){

            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) iview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                Log.e("Shiva","Came inside drawable");
        } else {
            Log.e("Shiva","drawable is null"+drawable);
            return null;

        }

        Uri bmpUri = null;

        File file =  new File(listdisplay.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // **Warning:** This will fail for API >= 24, use a FileProvider as shown below instead.

   return bmpUri;

    }
```

So, what happened now is in the if step where it is checking "drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable" is always returns null. whats wrong here? 
Note: Above code are inside the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can load image using this :

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*hcfIq_37pabmAOnw3rhvGA.png")
            .asBitmap()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    Log.d("Size ", "width :"+resource.getWidth() + " height :"+resource.getHeight());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    storeImage(resource);
                }
            });
```

And store bitmap to external storage and then share it.

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "img dir: " + pictureFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    File mediaFile;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 1000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String mImageName = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";

    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iview.getDrawable() will return null when using Glide.
You can set:

```
public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
               viewholder.iview.setDrawable(resource);
               return true;
             }
```

then iview.getDrawable() will return drawable

Comment: Not worked. i am getting null drawable is null. I logged the drawable i am getting below   in Andriod monitor com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.GlideBitmapDrawable@a696d2.

Comment: Try to add .load(Limage).asBitmap()

Comment: or use this ((GlideBitmapDrawable)view.getDrawable().getCurrent()).getBitmap()

Comment: Using both options image is passing but problem is when i click on first image second one is sharing and for remaining it is null.

Comment: I would recomend you to store 'Limage' and then download to file

Answer (score 1):

```
// Pass the Activity Context, ImageView, Image path which is located inside sdcard,And  default Image you want to display to
loadImageWithGlide Method.

loadImageWithGlide(this,imageView,imagePath,R.drawable.damaged_image,R.drawable.damaged_image);


// Method to Load Image from Sdcard to ImageView With Using Glide Library
public static void loadImageWithGlide(final Context context, ImageView theImageViewToLoadImage,
                                          String theLoadImagePath, int theDefaultImagePath, int tehErrorImagePath) {
        if (context == null) return;

        Glide.with(context) //passing context
                .load(theLoadImagePath) //passing your url to load image.
                .placeholder(theDefaultImagePath) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                .error(tehErrorImagePath)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                //.animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                .fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                .into(theImageViewToLoadImage); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.

    }


// Bellow is Code to share Image 
// Note: The image needed to located inside Sdcard. Pass that path inside Share Method.

public static void share(Context theCtx, String theImagePath, String theText) {
        File myImageFile = new File(theImagePath);
        String shareBody = theText;  //"Here is the share content body " ;
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        if (myImageFile.exists()) {
            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + myImageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        } else if (!theText.isEmpty()) {
            sharingIntent.setType("text/*");
        }
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""); //"Subject here"
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        theCtx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cache in memory with your image than you can extract it, otherwise is null, may be destroyed.

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Please explain why this would work so that others can learn from your contribution. Thanks.